# Jackson serialization doesn't include type info for Exception field

Tags: java, exception, jackson

I am using Jackson Object Mapper 2.10.

I am creating my ObjectMapper instance like below:

```
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper =
                new ObjectMapper().activateDefaultTyping(BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
                                                                                      .allowIfBaseType(Object.class)
                                                                                      .build());
```

I am trying to serialize a object of `TestClass` class defined below

```
class TestClass {
   Map<String, TestException> exceptionMap;
}

class TestException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

However, when I do `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)`, I get

```
{
  "exceptionMap": [
    "java.util.HashMap",
    {
      "key": 
        {
          "exception": {
            "cause": {
              "cause": null,
              "localizedMessage": "causeMessage",
              "message": "causeMessage",
              "stackTrace": [],
              "suppressed": []
            },
            "localizedMessage": "message",
            "message": "message",
            "stackTrace": [],
            "suppressed": []
          }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Type info of Exception objects is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get type information for all types including Exceptions by using below configuration:

```
new ObjectMapper().activateDefaultTyping(
  BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
     .allowIfBaseType(Object.class)
     .build(), 
  ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING);
```